# jQuery - Hiding text

Tags: jquery, hide

I have the following code and trying to hide `XYZ`. Why isn't it getting hidden using this code?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
               $('#hide').hide();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hide">
XYZ
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're not including the jQuery library.

Comment: Check your browser's error console. Also, you're including `jquery.js` before your script, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a reference to jQuery in order to use jQuery functions

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#hide').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using jQuery syntax, but you didn't add jQuery itself, that's why.

Add this to the head tag, before your current script block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery.js in your source file.

Answer (score 2):

You are not loading jQuery.

try to load it from Google:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js'></script>
```

before your script.

Comment: @JamWaffles: IMO, it's never appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to include jQuery library

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.js'></script>
```